# What is $ds$ in centroid equation's $\int y\space ds$?

Tags: differential-geometry, centroid

I'm looking at the equations for finding the centroid.

For the y-coordinate it is:
$$\frac{\int y\space ds}{\int ds}$$

${\int ds}$ is defined to be the *curve length*. But what then is $ds$ in $\int y \space ds$?
Is it the derivative of ${\int ds}$?

Comment: No, it is the infinitesimal element of arc length along the curve. If the curve is the graph of a function $y$ of $x$, $ds = \sqrt{1 + (y')^2} dx$.

Comment: How do you find $ds$?

Comment: It depends on how the curve is specified. If it is a graph, it's given by the formula mentioned in my previous comment. If it is given by a $C^1$ parameterization $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, $ds = \sqrt{(x')^2 + (y')^2} dt$.

Comment: So is it inside the integral or not? Like is $\int y \space ds$ = $(\int y)(ds)$ or $\int (yds)$?

Comment: If you like it is *part* of the integral. If you like, given a curve $\gamma$, $$\int_{\gamma} \underline{\phantom{m}} \,ds$$ is an indecomposable machine into which we put (nice) functions $y$ defined along $\gamma$ and get out a number, just like, given an interval $[a, b] \subset \Bbb R$,
$$\int_a^b \underline{\phantom{m}} \,dx$$ is a machine into which one puts nice functions $f: [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ and gets out the net signed area under the graph of $f$.